# asp.net mvc create development environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a production asp.net mvc website that I have been modifying and publishing through Visual Studio Express 2013. I wanted to create a development environment so that I'm not making changes to the production site/database. So, I did the following:

1. cloned the database and called it db-proj-dev
2. copied the source files for the project into a new folder called dbproj.dev
3. added the dev proj (dbproj.dev) to the same solution as the production project (so that easier to copy code from dev to prod)
4. modified web.config to point to the cloned database db-proj-dev
5. created a new publish profile pointing to dbproj.dev under inetpub
6. added a new website in IIS manager, pointing to the folder dbproj.dev under inetpub (port 10000 and same url as the default website)

What is happening now is that, when I bring up the dev site, it comes up to the home screen of the dev site, but if I click any of the links, it redirects to the main prod site. If I complete a form, the data gets posted to the production database. Does anyone know what I am forgetting or missing?

Comment: Yes, I did. I found a custom .js file that had hard-coded URLs. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :-) I've converted my comment to an answer, but you should self answer with the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have absolute links in there - `http://yoursite.com/thing/somepage` rather than relative `/thing/somepage`.